# How to check if an email address is fake ?

Tags: email, email-validation

I need to know how check if email address is valid without using link in email confirmation.
How can I do this?

Comment: There is another option to ask the smtp server what he will say about this mail using telnet or sites like this one https://checkeremail.com

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't, end of story.

Even using email confirmation only proves that the email address was valid at that time. It could then be shut down a second later!

Same for any other Internet based ID systems like OpenID, they can be set up and shut down just for the duration of the registration process. Even credit card ID can be one off since the invention of the disposable "debit" credit card.

Only government ID systems are likely to be valid for any length of time. There are major security implications when collecting and validating government ID's though, and it is different for each country.

It would be easier if all the governments could work together on one common system with a shared validation system including biometrics. Then Mossad couldn't steal passports so easily! They should set up a global community to organise it, maybe they could call it the UN? It shouldn't take long to sort out :-)

Comment: @Panique Care to explain yourself? Or edit the post, and update it for 2013 :-)

Comment: I've been already bashed for posting this, but this post on LIFEHACKER says something different: [How to Verify if an Email Address Is Real or Fake](http://lifehacker.com/5697360/how-to-verify-if-an-email-address-is-real-or-fake). However, you have to automate this to make it useful in real world applications.

Comment: @Panique Lifehacker is not an authoritative source, read the comments there! Pinging a server is in many cases not going to prove anything, and in fraud situations my posts first few paragraphs still stand

Answer (score 14):

You can't.  There's a reason everyone does it like that.  But you could use OpenID instead.

Comment: This is simply wrong. There are a lot of patterns to narrow down the existance of a certain email adress. You'll never get a 100% secure result, but still enough to keep your costs down.

Comment: @Panique, it's not wrong.  As you admit yourself, without sending an email you can only make an educated guess.  I think you're exaggerating the cost of sending a verification email.  And most of the time, if you want an email at sign up, you plan to send emails later anyway.

Answer (score 8):

There's no way to know if an email address is fake.

But you can:

- Check if the address domain exists
- Send an email to the address with a confirmation key to be returned

Comment: when you say "check if the address exists", do you mean waiting for a response from the server telling you there is no such email address?

Comment: actually I meant checking if the address domain exists. I edited the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make sure if an email id is fake or real, but you can check if the mail has come from an original server or not.

For example: if the mail id is `xyz@google.com` then it should come from google server, but if it comes from some other server then it has a high probability of being fake. You can check the original code of email, in gmail,hotmail show original option shows full code,and in yahoo you can see the code in option show header.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by coding an application that simply do a reverse lookup for domain, once ok send a test email and check for the right reply codes. There is also a verify VRFY command in last SMTP protocol specs  RFC-5321, check here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-3.5.2