# MX records of a remote domain without NS information

Tags: c#, .net, dns, mx-record

I am building a SMTP diagnostics tool by using c# 4.0
If I know the IP Address of Primary NS of a domain, I can get MX,A and CNAME records.
So I can validate any email and run legal diagnostics commands. , if I can connect to mail server.

My problem is that I could not find a proper .NET solution to get Primary NS for a given domain.

I know there are some managed clients but I can not add them as reference to my solution or their source code is closed.

What is the differences of managed code and .NET for this issue , that managed code can query NS of a domain and .NET can not as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7790810/574414). ?

What is the proper way to implement such a kind of functionality ?

Regards

Comment: Which managed clients could you not add as a reference?

Comment: Well,this is a hard question :) I don't remember.After trying so many things and getting error , I've deleted them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the IP of your DNS server using IPInterfaceProperties.DnsAddresses. A code example can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.dnsaddresses.aspx

You can then query that server using the component found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12072/C-NET-DNS-query-component

You can find the primary DNS server by querying for SOA records.

```
List<IPAddress> dnsServers = new List<IPAddress>();

NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
{
    IPInterfaceProperties adapterProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
    IPAddressCollection adapterDnsServers = adapterProperties.DnsAddresses;

    if (adapterDnsServers.Count > 0)
        dnsServers.AddRange(adapterDnsServers);
}

foreach (IPAddress dnsServer in (from d in dnsServers 
                                where d.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork
                               select d))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Using server {0}", dnsServer);

    // create a request
    Request request = new Request();

    // add the question
    request.AddQuestion(new Question("stackoverflow.com", DnsType.MX, DnsClass.IN));

    // send the query and collect the response
    Response response = Resolver.Lookup(request, dnsServer);

    // iterate through all the answers and display the output
    foreach (Answer answer in response.Answers)
    {
        MXRecord record = (MXRecord)answer.Record;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}), preference {2}", record.DomainName, Dns.GetHostAddresses(record.DomainName)[0], record.Preference);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You can access local interfaces, not remote interfaces.And remote domain firewalls will never let you access their interface.

Comment: You get your interfaces, so you get your DNS server's IP, so you can query it for the SOA record for a remote domain, so you can query that NS for the MX record. (Although you might as well query your NS for the MX records.)

Comment: Let's say that my local IP is 192.168.1.10 and my Default Gateway and Primary DNS Server are 192.168.1.1. I don't think I can query SOA for a remote domain on my local DNS or router but remote NS server.