# Is there an implementable (non-theoretical) way to prove if email address belong to real email account?

Tags: java, php, bash, email

Is there a way to prove that a certain email address is "real", therefore belongs to a really existing email account ? I get masses of registrations via emails that are valid according to email pattern definition, but do not really exist. Sending to fake mail addresses costs a lot of money, as we (and others) pay per mail (100.000 sendings to fake mail accounts can cost you four-digit numbers per year, just to show a number). **I want to check for exactly that moment. We don't care if the email adress is offline 1 minute later.**

An ideal solution would be a bash one-liner (that could be called with every major language).

**What i have done so far:**

1. Checking [this similar 3yo thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366734/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-is-fake), which is simply wrong for a real-world case. I want to check if an email adress exist, in the moment i'm sending a mail (to prevent costs).
2. checking if the hostname is pingable.
3. checking if the email adress is pingable, like [here](http://lifehacker.com/5697360/how-to-verify-if-an-email-address-is-real-or-fake). I tried to rebuild this in a bash script, but failed (fetching the adress is hard!).

**What i really want:**

A reliable check if the mail account exists implementable by the average coder, in PHP or Java. A bash one-liner or a php/java library that does exactly this. Free or commercial.

*I'll provide bounty!*

Comment: Out of curiosity, is that number real?

Comment: Are those direct costs or indirect costs of the amount of hardware required to handle the sending of the emails?

Comment: wouldn't all the spammers of world like to know this!

Comment: I am an email kinda guy, and I can tell you there is no solution to the problem you pose.  You might consider using a 'white list' service to help your emails get to their destinations.

Comment: Hosts are not required to respond to echo requests, so pinging the smtp server is not really a valid test.

Comment: The only way I can think of is using a double opt-in method (reply or link click). But you are probably looking for checking before you send the message.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That number is really high, but indeed showing the dimension (when calculated per year). 1.000.000 (fake) SMTP mails costs you $500 PER MONTH, 200.000 fake mailing list users costs you $800 PER MONTH. Account verification etc can do a lot, but there are scenarios where this hurts, for example "public watcher services" that simply accept mail adresses without account creation and without captchas etc.! And btw, I have not built this crap ;)

Comment: i don't understand what the problem is with #3 above?  are you saying it doesn't work?

Comment: @jtahlborn No no ! I just said that the logic behind this is hard to translate into a bash script (or PHP maybe). The example is manual, but here we need an automated solution.

Comment: you asked for a solution an average programmer could implement in php or java.  i'm pretty sure the average programmer could implement that solution in java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if an email address is fake ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366734/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-is-fake)

Answer (score 6):

It's called "double opt-in".

1. The user enters their email address in your registration form.
2. The user clicks a box that says "yes, please email me".
3. You send an email to that user along the lines of "Hi, this is to confirm your account. Please click **this link**."
4. Once the link is clicked you have as much confirmation that you're ever going to get, and you're less likely to either be a spammer, or be mistaken for one.

Other such magic spells for not wasting paid emails are:

- "using a mailer that knows what a 500-level SMTP error means" [aka, not `mail()`] and deleting that person from your list.
- "Bounce Processing" and deleting that person from your list.
- "A working unsubscribe process" that works, and also deletes that person from your list. Did I mention that is should *work*?

If you [or anyone reading this] have not gathered your email lists voluntarily without at least *some level* of the user *opting in* there's an advanced technique that us email admins call "pissing up a rope" where you hang a length of rope from a high place and see how high up it from directly beneath it.

Comment: This might be a useful standard for application that use accounts, but for some use cases this is not appliable. For example, one of my clients offers "watcher notifications" for a mainstream audience. If people want to be noticed about something, let's say product price updates, then they can request mail updates by simply submitting their email adresses. No sign in, no verification. I don't say that this is a good implementation, but this is quite common in some of the leading european websites.

Answer (score 4):

email admins may elect to have all attempt to send an "OK" even if the the address you are sending to does not exist.  I do this in part to make it harder for spammers to "learn" the address in my domain.

A better practice would be to require registration via a web form with captcha (of some kind) that then sends a verification email, rather then accepting mass registration via email. (if you are not doing this already).

If you have a sufficient history to build off of, you might want to create a black list of known bad email address to reference prior to sending.  How many of your registrants are `mailadmin@yourdomain.com`  or `root@google.com`?

For my business, we host a SMTP server locally to avoid costs associated with failed delivery on legitimate email campaigns.  Otherwise I would be burning money and shoveling sand in to the sea.

Answer (score 3):

The SMTP protocol is not designed to provide a means to check for the availability of a mailbox.

When delivering an email, usually these steps are taken:

#### Check MX record of mail domain

A mail to `somebody@example.com` will check whether there are MX records for `example.com`. If there are some, the one with the highest priority will be contacted to accept the mail. If it doesn't respond, any existing MX with lower priority will be contacted.

If there is no MX record, a search for the "A" record of `example.com` will take place, and that IP will be connected to accept the mail.

#### Connection to the server mentioned in MX or A record

The receiving mail server is contacted. If it exists, mail MIGHT get delivered. The SMTP protocol requires the sending mailserver to send the receiving mail address, the sending mail address, and then the mail itself.

#### The receiving mail server tries to deliver the mail into the users mailbox

This might fail for several reasons. And the important info is that this step might take place AFTER the sending mailserver got a positive reply that the mail was received, and the connection was terminated. So the sending mailserver might get NO clue that the delivery failed.

The receiving mailserver will send a bounce message in this case. But this bounce mail is sent to the mail address that is designated to receive errors. This might be the original mail address, but could also be a different one. And additionally, the responsible mailserver to receive the bounce must not be the server that sent the original mail.

At this point it should be pretty clear that email really is an asynchronous information exchange medium with barely any reliability built-in.

Some techniques make it feasible though to hope for slight improvements: Usually the sending of bounce messages is not the best idea. Well configured mail servers reject receiving mail for mailboxes that have any problem, like they do not exist, or are full.

On the other hand, the new big black hole for mail are spam filters. Usually these are configured by the user, and the mail server will happily receive any mail for the existing mailbox, but then the spam gets automatically deleted or moved to a spam folder and ignored.

Also, there is a technology like greylisting, that answers any attempt to deliver a mail with a temporary failure state. A normal mailserver will try at a later time, and eventually the greylisting timer is over (might be over an hour in some settings), and a REAL delivery attempt is made, with a real final rejection or acceptance. Meanwhile, the mailserver hopes for it's included spam filters to detect new waves of spam mail, and greylisting really only buys some time. Any regular delivery attempt by well known mail servers will succeed instantly, because successful non-spam mail delivery gets whitelisted.

After all that description of how real mail works, I think you can see that there really is no way to "simply" detect whether a mail address really really exists. The only thing you can do is to TRY detecting whether it exists, and if you positively get told that the mailbox does not exist, because the target mailserver denies delivery, you can assume that you probably should no longer try to deliver mail to that target.

Any other result does not tell you anything. And you'll also note that detecting if a mail address exists requires you to send a mail - catch-22 situation.

You really should implement a proper bounce management and delivery failure detection to remove obvious failing mail addresses. Anything else is undetectable.