# How to filter and handle fake emails with Mandrill?

Tags: php, email, mandrill

With Mandrill 1.0.* and PHP 5.5 :

I have to manage a database of users (with sign up, notifications, etc), sending them emails with Mandrill.

Mandrill has a "reputation" system that handicaps you if you send too many emails to fake addresses (something like fezfzeyhzegfyz4354dez3@gmail.com I guess).

So how should I handle those fake emails and "blacklist" them within Mandrill or my database ?

How do Facebook, SoundCloud, and others handle robots that spam the sign up form with fake emails ? (if those robots ever exist)

I can't find a Mandrill check DNS feature or anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mailchecker](https://github.com/FGRibreau/mailchecker#php) is your friend:

```
if(!MailChecker('myemail@yopmail.com')){
  die('O RLY !');
}

if(!MailChecker('myemail.com')){
  die('O RLY !');
}
```

Comment: Oh that is a nice plugin ! So basically it filters temporary emails and robot emails. What about random emails that a user enters on the fly like **iwillenterastupidemail@gmail.com**. MailChecker will accept them. Is this scenario rare enough for me to just ignore it ?

Comment: It could happen and I don't think there is a real way to recognize them. [Check also this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2366734/1992780).